# Bootstrap Modal gets disappeared immidiately

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i have a modal which i want to show on click..but when i make it on button click , it get disappeared immediately after loading...
but when i set it to show on windows onload it works properly i.e. does not disappear immediately..

the code i've used to show modal is

```
 $("#addnewrm").click(function () {
            $('#add').modal('show');
        });
```

The `<div id='add',class='modal fade'....` is in partial view (AddRawMaterial.cshtml)

im rendering this partial view (AddRawMaterial.cshtml) in
`@{Html.RenderPartial("../Shared/AddRawMaterial", this.Model);}`
in my index.cshtml

Comment: What is #addnewrm?

Comment: id of button @JamesS

Comment: Is the button a submit?

Comment: no its just a button type="button"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that was just because of button..
when i changed button to anchor(`<a>`)tag and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Make sure bootstrap.js is only included once in the view where you're experiencing this issue.